# Date in header of soap response

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

Am writing a CXF based web service. I need to pass date in response header as local server time , but this is getting returned as GMT, as show below

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.2.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_2_GA date=200710221139)/Tomcat-5.5
Date: Mon, 28 Aug 2017 06:47:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 436
```

But if i set a value Date1 as header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.2.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_2_GA date=200710221139)/Tomcat-5.5
Date1: Mon Aug 28 12:38:47 IST 2017
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 436
Date: Mon, 28 Aug 2017 07:08:47 GMT
```

Can't we able to override *Date* here ,if yes can some one help me out from this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit http headers before message is sent, then you can create interceptor, add it to outgoing interceptors and do it there.

```
public class HttpHeaderInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message>{

public HttpHeaderInterceptor() {
 super(Phase.POST_LOGICAL);
 }

public void handleMessage(Message message) {
 Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
 headers.put("xxx", "yyyy");
 message.put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, headers);
 }

}
```